# Move 2 CCSprite with UITouch

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, move, ccsprite

I try make a simple game in cocos2d at now i have something like that

```
#import "GameplayLayer.h"

@implementation GameplayLayer
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
        // właczenie obsługi dotyku
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

        }
        else{
            paddle1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bijakiPhone.png"];
            paddle2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bijakiPhone.png"];
            puck = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"krazekiPhone.png"];
        }
        //Polozenie i inicjalizacja paletki nr 1
        [paddle1 setPosition:
         CGPointMake(screenSize.width/2,
                     screenSize.height*0.17f)];
        [self addChild:paddle1];
        //Polozenie i inicjalizacja paletki nr 2
        [paddle2 setPosition:
         CGPointMake(screenSize.width/2,
                     screenSize.height*0.83f)];
        [self addChild:paddle2];
        //Polozenie i inicjalizacja krązka
        [puck setPosition:CGPointMake(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2)];
        [self addChild:puck];
    }
    return self;
}
//onEnter
- (void)onEnter
{
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
    [super onEnter];
}

//onExit
- (void)onExit
{
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate:self];
    [super onExit];
}
-(BOOL)containsTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    CGRect r=[paddle1 textureRect];
    CGPoint p=[paddle1 convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
    return CGRectContainsPoint(r, p );
}
-(BOOL)containsTouch2:(UITouch *)touch {
    CGRect r=[paddle2 textureRect];
    CGPoint p=[paddle2 convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
    return CGRectContainsPoint(r, p );
}
-(BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([self containsTouch:touch]){
       CCLOG(@"krarzek 1 tapniety");
        isTouched1 = YES;
    }


    if ([self containsTouch2:touch]){
        CCLOG(@"krarzek 2 tapniety");
        isTouched2 = YES;
    }

    return YES;
}
-(void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if (isTouched1){
        CGPoint newTouchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        newTouchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:newTouchLocation];
        [paddle1 setPosition:newTouchLocation];

    }


    if (isTouched2){
        CGPoint newTouchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        newTouchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:newTouchLocation];
        [paddle2 setPosition:newTouchLocation];
    }

}
-(void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if (isTouched1){
        isTouched1=NO;
        CCLOG(@"krarzek 1 zwolniony");
}
    if (isTouched2){
        isTouched2=NO;
        CCLOG(@"krarzek 2 zwolniony");
    }
}
@end
```

Works CCSprite move, but when i touch 2 CCSprite at same time, They overlap itself!
How i can move them separately?
Sorry for my English and Thanks for help!

Comment: multipletouch is enabled? Use setMultipleTouchEnabled:Yes for your UIWindow or UIView, and then set the isTouchEnabled property for the layer on which you want to receive touches. Then try out

Comment: Yes, i have:  [glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES]; in AppDelegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of your problem that you don't store somewhere what touch is connected to your paddle. So in case of both touches are inside your paddle sprites, both `isTouched1` and `isTouched2` variables have value `YES`. So in your `ccTouchMoved:withEvent:` method both sprites will be placed to the same position in this case. Store your touches in some variable or I suggest to use dictionary for this with touch as a key and sprite that you need to move as value. In this case your `ccTouchMoved:withEvent:` method will be look like this

```
-(void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
        CGPoint newTouchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        newTouchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:newTouchLocation];
        CCNode paddle = [_yourDict objectForKey: touch];
        [paddle setPosition:newTouchLocation];
}
```

And names of your methods that determine if sprite contains given touch are not good enough. I could not say what they do without looking through the code.